# Как обратиться к нужному контексту?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

В библиотеке `react-highcharts` конфиг позволяет реализовывать ивенты по клику. Происходит это так:

```
plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click:  function () {  
                            this.props.chartMeasureClick(this.series.options.id);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

И ействительно при клике в данном случае я получаю нужный `this.series.options.id` , однако метод `this.props.chartMeasureClick` является `undefined`. Почитав гуггл, решение нашлось переделать `function (){}`  в `()=>{}` и действительно, ошибка исчезла, НО теперь `this.series.options.id = undefined` , потому что this ссылается на контекст уровнем выше(на саму компоненту). Как мне достучаться до нужного контекста в данном случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут как раз ваш случай. Попробуйте один из предложенных вариантов: https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts/issues/348

Либо попробуйте записать в `plotOptions` ссылку на *this* компонента и использовать обычную (не стрелочную функцию). Как-то так:

```
plotOptions: {
  that: this, // <--- here

  series: {
    ...
    point: {
      events: {
        click: getClickHandler(this)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ещё идея с замыканием:

```
function getClickHandler(context) {
  var that = context;
  return function () {  
    that.props.chartMeasureClick(this.series.options.id);
  }
}
```

Comment: там они предлагают решение в виде стрелочной функции,которое я уже пробовал. если исопльзовать его, меняется контекст и я теряю некоторые данные. вопробовал вариант с that, пишет, что that is not defined

Comment: А если передавать **that** в функцию? Виден он или нет? (Обновил ответ)

Comment: А, нет, это тоже вряд ли поможет. Попробуйте последний вариант (обновил ответ)

Comment: сработало!только я определил that=this вне объекта конфига, нов методе где он формируется, чтобы this ссылался на компоненту и все заработало без переделываниея клика в стрелочную функцию.большое спасибо

Comment: Ну здорово! А с замыканием не пробовали?